# Аргументы метода

Tags: java

Двумерный массив состоит из String "X" и String "O". Я по нему пробегаюсь и ищу кол-во X и O. Ну естественно сохраняю их в счетчики. Point - это адрес ячеек по координатам x и y. Так вот я хочу через метод getFigure получить то, что там

```
public class Point {

    public int x;
    public int y;
}
public class Field {


    public String[][] figures = new String[3][3];

    public int getSize() {
        return figures.length;
    }

    public String getFigure(final Point point) {
        return figures[point.x][point.y];
    }

}
public class Current {
public String currentMove(final Field field) {

    int countX = 0;
    int countY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < field.getSize(); i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < field.getSize(); k++){
            if (field.getFigure(???)){
                countX++;
            }     
    }

}
```

Вот туда надо вставить Point. Не понимаю как. Подскажите. Только именно объясните )

Comment: Объясните подробнее, что код делает сейчас и какой именно результат Вы ожидаете получить. Иначе есть риск, что и здесь будут долго отвечать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не особо понятно исходное задание, но можно попробовать так:

```
Point point = new Point();
point.x = i;
point.y = k;
if (field.getFigure(point)){
    countX++;
}
```

Создаем экземпляр класса `Point`:

```
Point point = new Point();
```

Задаем поля (Лучше делать через конструктор):

```
point.x = i;
point.y = k;
```

Также метод `Field.getFigure` возвращает строку, поэтому его нельзя прямо использовать в конструкции `if`. Если предполагалась проверка на `X`, то ее нужно писать явно:

```
if (field.getFigure(point).equals("X")) {}
```